# AngularJS отследить добавление(изменения) класса элементу

Tags: angularjs, классы

Есть некий контейнер c классом 'rowemail', к которому каким-то неизвестным способом добавляется некий класс 'error'

```
<div class="rowemail" test-test>
    Hello World
</div>
```

Как отследить событие добавление класса 'error'?
Пробовал через директиву testTest с помощью `$observe` но ничего не получилось

```
function testTest() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('class', function () {
               console.log(attrs.class);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[Мой пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/btNz1h65HZ1jIhzUAj1w?p=preview)

Comment: А почему способ добавления класса вам неизвестен? Насколько я знаю, если дело доходит до `$watch` / `$observe`, то это результат неправильной архитектуры кода. По самому вопросу гуглится что-то такое: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693064/monitor-for-class-changing-on-element-in-angularjs-directive и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911300/is-it-possible-to-watch-attributes-changes.

Comment: серверная часть написана на Yii (php фрэймворк). Там есть виджет - форма, если форма не проходит аякс валидацию(аякс валидация встроенная в виджет), то элементу добавляется класс error. Вот и нужно отследить это событие

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/OAHmeJj255JZGOqby3k9?p=preview если изменение происходит при нажатии кнопки в консоль выводится новый класс, но это не работает в моем проекте, когда изменение класса происходит "извне"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для новых браузеров и IE>=11 можно использовать [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```js
// Code goes here

// Code goes here
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function mainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.changeClass = function() {

    }
  })
  .directive('testTest', function testTest() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        't': '=testTest'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
          mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            console.log(mutation.type, mutation);
            
          });
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.t = element.attr('class');
          });
        });
        // configuration of the observer:
        var config = {
          attributes: true,
          attributeFilter: ['class']
        };

        // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
        observer.observe(element[0], config);
        scope.$on('destroy', function() {
          observer.disconnect();
        });
      }
    }
  });

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('test').classList.add('error');
});
```

```css
.rowemail {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div id='test' class="rowemail" test-test="t">
    {{t}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="btn" />
  </div>
```